# Mutually exclusive options depending on condition: "It will be possible or not, depending on ..."

Tags: conjunctions, negation, ellipsis, coordination

What are the common ways to express this kind of sentence:

> "It will be possible **or not**, depending on ..."
>
> "It will be possible **or it will not**, depending on..."

Are they correct? If not, how can I say it?

Comment: I think *"It will or will not be possible (to ...), depending on ..."* might be possible, but *"It may or may not be possible (to ...), depending on ..."* is more common and quite close to your sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can phrase this as:

> *< Some factor >* will determine if it is possible.

For example:

> The time we arrive will determine whether we'll be able to get gas or not.

or

> Whether John was able to get the key [or not] will determine if we'll be able to get in tonight.

You can also use *dictate* in place of *determine*

> Whether they can score in the next 2 minutes will dictate the outcome of the game.